# Unknown clients upon running knife client list

Tags: knife, chef-infra

I have been using chef automation for a while. My setup has an open source chef server installed on ubuntu12.04 and 2 virtual machines with centos6.5 and ubuntu12.04 as nodes.

But when I run `knife client list` from my workstation it gives me the result as
[image]

ubuntu and dhcppc5 are 2 valid nodes.

On deleting the bogus nodes by "knife client delete"

I get error as:
[image]

What are these unknown clients and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you run `chef-server-ctl test`? The pedant users are created during the test suite.

Comment: Yes I did. But how to remove them from the list I am not able to remove them without getting error.

Comment: Did you stop the test midway - the test should delete those

Comment: Nope I didn't stop in between. I waited for the test to finish and then ran the command from my workstation.

Comment: I would recommend filing an issue with support

Answer (score -1):

What version of chef server?

If 11 do the clients show up in the web interface?

what happens if you create one with the same name?